# Lower bound on ratio of extreme order statistics

Tags: st.statistics, stochastic-calculus, order-theory

This question relates to bounds on expectations of order statistics, elaborated upon in the Book by Arnold and Balakrishnan (1989). Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. continuous random variables distributed on a positive and finite interval $[0,1]$. Denote by $\mu_i=E[X_i]$ and $\sigma_i^2=var(X_i)$. Let $F$ denote the corresponding parent CDF, and $\mu,\sigma^2$ denote it's associated mean and variance. Furthermore, let $X_{1:n}\leq X_{2:n}\leq \ldots\leq X_{n:n}$ denote the corresponding order statistics with expectations $\mu_{1:n},\ldots,\mu_{n:n}$. Under homogeneity assumptions (i.e., $\forall i:\mu_i=\mu,\sigma_i^2=\sigma^2$) we may bound the expectations of a general order statistic as follows:

$$-\sigma \sqrt{\frac{n-i}{i}}\leq\mu_{i:n}-\mu\leq\sigma \sqrt{\frac{i-1}{n-i+1}},$$

defined by Theorem 3.19, Arnold and Balakrishnan (1989). In the particular case of $n=2$, the lower bound on the maximum and the upper bound on the minimum are trivial cases since,
$$-\sigma \leq\mu_{1:2}-\mu\leq0, \mathrm{\quad and\quad}0\leq\mu_{2:2}-\mu\leq\sigma,$$provide no useful information in terms of variance.

The extension of Hawkings (1971) on the bounds of extreme order statistics is applicable only in the deterministic case. An extension to distributions defined on a positive interval from Papados (1996) is defined without variance. In a recent paper Rychlik (2014) shows that the bound $$\frac{\mu_{1:n}-\mu}{\sigma}\leq 0$$ is achievable also in increasing density (ID) and increasing failure rate (IFR) distributions. As to my reading (although it seems counter-intuitive), the above bounds on extreme order statistics seem to hold.

In the particular problem I have in mind, I need a mean-variance bound on the ratio of the extreme order statistics. From the above inequalities, one could derive that

$$1\leq\frac{\mu_{2:2}}{\mu_{1:2}}\leq\frac{\mu+\sigma}{\mu-\sigma}.$$

The obtained lower bound is very trivial since, at least to my understanding, the lower bound should also depend on the mean and variance. Intuitively, an increase in the variance would push the expectations of the order statistics away from the mean (which may not be centered). Following questions are open

1.) How could a lower bound on the ratio of extreme order statistics in terms of $(\mu,\sigma)$ look like for a broad class (possibly IFR) of distributions look like? As @Matt.F developed, a necessary condition for his established bound
$$\frac{\mu+\frac{\sigma}{2}}{\mu-\frac{\sigma}{2}}\leq\frac{\mu_{2:2}}{\mu_{1:2}}$$
is $\sigma\leq \mu_{2:2}-\mu_{1:2}$. This somehow relates to the class of IFR distributions since the exponential is the limiting case.

2.) The bound
$$\frac{\mu_{2:2}}{\mu_{1:2}}\leq\frac{\mu+\sigma}{\mu-\sigma}$$
seems to be overly loose for standard distributions. I hope to establish
$$\frac{\mu_{2:2}}{\mu_{1:2}}\leq\frac{\mu+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{3}}}{\mu-\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{3}}\sigma},$$
which seems to hold for a broad class of distributions, with the uniform as the limiting case.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer depending on $\mu,\sigma,a$ or just depending on $\mu,\sigma$, with $a$ allowed to take any finite value?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $a$ is indeed assumed to take on any finite value. For the sake of simplicity just assume $a=1$. The bound fits all my purposes :), may I ask you to sketch how you have derived it?

Comment: Done. May I just remark that the bound you have suggested does not depend on $a$? I was assuming you were setting $a=1$ anyway. I see, well to provide help for the derivation let me just add that the binary distribution and shifted exponential distribution as limiting cases do not surprise me too much, as the exponential exhibits a constant failure rate.

Comment: Assuming IFR, i.e., $f/(1-F)$ is strictly increasing, could provide a restriction on the class of distributions which may be adequate for your suggestion. The classical reference here is Barlow & Proschan (1966), elaborated upon in the books of Arnold & Balakrishnan (1989, end of Chapter 3) - but this goes beyond my stochastic understanding. Do your bounds also hold for DFR distributions?

Comment: I added the upper bound to my new answer; meanwhile, I deleted my original comments here, amd you can delete your older comments if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The **upper bound**
$$\frac{\mu_{2:2}}{\mu_{1:2}} 
=\frac{\mu+(\mu_{2:2}-\mu_{1:2})/2}{ \mu-(\mu_{2:2}-\mu_{1:2})/2)}
\le \frac{\mu + \sigma/\sqrt3}{\mu - \sigma/\sqrt3}$$
follows from the bound $\mu_{2:2}-\mu_{1:2}\le2\sigma/\sqrt3$, as at
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493274/an-upper-bound-of-mean-absolute-difference.

There is **no lower bound** of the form
$$\frac{\mu_{2:2}}{\mu_{1:2}} \ge \frac{\mu + k\sigma}{\mu - k\sigma}$$
with a fixed $k>0$.

Consider the following distribution with support $[0,1]$:
\begin{align}
\text{pdf: } f(x)&=bx^{b-1}\\
\text{cdf: } F(x)&=x^b\\
\text{quantile: } Q(p)&=p^{1/b}\\
\mu &= \frac{b}{b+1}\\
\sigma &= \frac{1}{b+1}\sqrt{\frac{b}{2+b}}\\
\mu_{2:2} &= \frac{2b}{2b+1}\\
\mu_{1:2} &= \frac{2b^2}{(2b+1)(b+1)}\\
\mu_{2:2}/\mu_{1:2} &= 1+b^{-1}\\
\end{align}
So the above inequality is violated with $b=k^2/2$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the correction - so a restriction on the class of distributions is necessary. After some experiments it seems that $$\sigma\leq\mu_2-\mu_1$ could be established, assuming IFR, again with the exponential as the limiting case.